# Permutation Multiplication (easy)

Tags: permutations

Given α◦β=(1532)(14)(35)

How do we get from the given to = ( 1 4 5 2 ) ( 3 ) = ( 1 4 5 2 ) = 
(4 1 3 5 2) ?

Thanks

Comment: Work out where each number maps to.

Comment: $(1 4 5 2)(3)=(1 4 5 2)$?. Will someone explain. I don't understand this notation.

Comment: It's cyclic notation, the $(3)$ means keep $3$ constant, so it can be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easiest to write this out and compose from right to left as follows
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
5 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
4 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 5
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
4 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 2
\end{pmatrix} = (1452)
$$
For instance, you check $1 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 4$

Comment: That is very clear! Thanks. What about if we start counting from the 5th term in the pre last bracket, can we also say that it all equals to, say, (5 2 1 4), instead of (1 4 5 2)?

Comment: @user138913 as long as the order of the numbers in the cycle remains the same, they represent the same cycle.